# How to run multiple videos with different VideoViews in one activity in android 2.2?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using 3 videoViews for 3 diff. videos in one activity. Now If I am run the program in android 2.3.3 emulator then it runs perfectly but it can run only 1 video in android 2.2 emulator or device.....so how each video can run in android 2.2???
I am using following code to run each video....

```
VideoView vd = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.VideoViewShow);

     String uri1 = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.door_175_210;

     vd.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri1));
     vd.start();
```

Comment: You can try with Handlers/Thread for three different videos in the Android 2.2

Comment: You need to put 3 VideoView tag in layout.xml and then run 1 for each

Answer (score 2):

Known problem playing videos in android 2.2 read this thread: http://androidforums.com/droid-support-troubleshooting/141860-running-2-2-wont-play-some-videos.html